# How to hang up the calls before calling AGI script?

Tags: asterisk

I am new to asterisk. I had a below configuration in my extension.conf file.
I am hang up my call before AGI script executing (Ringing) then my call has got disconnected but still channel is occupied and AGI script is running in asterisk CLI.

I want to know how to hang up the AGI script execution while after my call has disconnected?

If I disconnect my call in ringing event, call has disconnected. But Asterisk is  not receiving my hangup signal and  my AGI script is started to executing.

```
How can I hangup the call without Answer() function?
```

[test]
   exten => s,1,Ringing
exten => s,2,Wait(8)
exten => s,3,AGI('testing.pl')

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score -1):

You have to use h extensions for and call your AGI script at hangup as

```
enter code here
```

[test]

exten => s,1,Ringing

exten => s,n,Wait(8)

exten => s,n,HangUp()

exten => h,1,AGI('testing.pl')

exten => h,2,NoOp(Done)

Comment: Never use like this. Under real load it will result kill of agi script and hang of asterisk core(stop accepting new calls)